# How do I draw a circuit for a conducting loop inside a solenoid?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, circuits, circuit-design, homework

To solve a homework problem, I need to redraw the following diagram in circuit form.

[image: diagram]

The large blue circle represents the solenoid. Inside the solenoid, the two gray semicircles represent a wire loop, through which current flows.

The two blue lines inside the wire loop represent additional pieces of wire.

The only resource I found in my textbook is a diagram of an inhomogeneous loop around a solenoid.

[image: diagram of example]

I tried to draw a circuit, but it doesn't seem correct.

[image: my attempt at a circuit]

I'm unsure how to proceed past this point.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include *detailed* descriptions of the different colours and shapes in the first picture. It is not clear which lines and shapes are physically present and which ones are just annotations. The question doesn't have enough information IMHO. Please also mention your attempts at solving the top figure.

Comment: I edited the post as requested.